# A question about my professor's "writing" in Function of several real variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble understanding what my teacher means by:

The norm of the linear operator $T:V\to W$, with $(V, \Vert{\circ}\Vert)$ and $(W, \Vert{\circ}\Vert)$ two normed vector spaces, is defined by: 
$$\Vert T \Vert:=\underbrace{\text{Sup}}_{v\in V, v\neq0}\frac{\Vert T_v \Vert_w}{\Vert v \Vert_v}$$ and observe that, if $T:V\to W$ is linear, then $$\Vert{T}\Vert:=\underbrace{\text{Sup}}_{v\in V, \Vert{v}\Vert=1}\Vert{T_v}\Vert_w$$

- What she meant by $\Vert{\circ}\Vert$?
- And about the $v$ in $\Vert T_v \Vert$ and the $w$ in $\Vert{T_v}\Vert_w$

Comment: I'm quite positve that $T_v$ should read as $Tv (=T(v))$ so you probably copied it wrongly? Also, the first supremum must be over $v\neq0$ not $v=0$. $\|\circ\|$ is just a notation used to represent a norm as a function. The subscript $w$ in $\|Tv\|_w$ is there to imply that this norm is norm on space $W$, not $V$.

Comment: $\Vert \circ \Vert$ means $x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert$. The subscripts outside of the norms should be capitalized and refer to the spaces in which the norms occur. The subscripts of $T$ inside of the norms are vectors and should not be subscripts.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys. I knew it was simple.

Comment: I think it is somehow overexposed. As $T\colon V\to W$ it is pretty clear that $\|Tv\|$ must be the $W$-norm to make sense. Otherwise, it is often the dot symbol $\|\cdot\|$ instead of the circle.